# ошибка при запуске бота "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Пытаюсь запустить бота тг, но выдает ошибку.
Прошу помочь

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stryg\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 15, in <module>
    URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + TG_API_TOKEN + '/'
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

вот мой код

```
from flask import Flask
import flask
from flask_sslify import SSLify
import telebot
import gspread
from datetime import datetime
import logging
from time import sleep
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TG_API_TOKEN = os.getenv('token')
SERVICE_ACCOUNT = os.getenv('service_account')
URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + TG_API_TOKEN + '/'
#
datem = datetime(datetime.today().year, datetime.today().month, 1)
app = Flask(__name__)
#
sslify = SSLify(app)
gc = gspread.service_account(filename=SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TG_API_TOKEN)
```

Comment: вы уверены, что у вас в переменной `TG_API_TOKEN` есть токен?

Comment: да, просто здесь заменил

Comment: ну ошибка говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь сделать конкатенацию строки и `NoneType` объекта, так что проверяйте, что у вас в `TG_API_TOKEN` точно строковое значение

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка появляется из-за того что выполнясь `os.getenv`, не находит переменную среды 'token' и возвращает значение из аргумента `default`, а т.к. он не задан `os.getenv` возвращает None. После мы пытаемся прибавить None к строке `'https://api.telegram.org/bot'`, а складывать строки и `None` python не умеет.
Для решения проблемы нужно либо добавить переменные среды `token` и `service_account`, либо заменить `os.getenv('token')` и `os.getenv('service_account')` на их значения. Вот так:

```py
TG_API_TOKEN = 'Вставить_Токен_Здесь'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT = 'Вставить_service_account_Здесь'
```